# How to get Linting in VSCode for Julia

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, lint

I think Julia is a great Language, but I find that there is a total lack of any error detection in VsCode.

Look at this code example:
[image: What VsCode shows]

I would expect that red squiggly lines show up in these places:
[image: Red lines]

1. StructABCNotDefined is not a valid type
2. |> operator not defined for Integers
3. Should not be able to call fun with a String as an argument
4. fun does not return something of type StructABCNotDefined

Without proper type checking working it's a total mess like python only that it runs a bit faster. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to setup VsCode to have these type checking abilities for Julia?

Comment: This is suitable for GitHub issues. You'll get the most accurate response if you raise an issue in the official GitHub of the extension and request a feature. However, I guess they already know the gaps in their extension.

Comment: Do you use Julia? How can you use the language without getting mad at stuff like this?

Comment: I use Julia every day and focus on not making mistakes like this. And these thing doesn't make me *mad*!

Comment: That's the thing, you need to *focus* on not making mistakes like that. That's not a good thing. It could be all avoided with static type checking in VSCode such that we can focus on things that actually matter.

Comment: Types are one of the most important *things* in Julia that highly *matter*. Anyway, you can open an issue and reach devs out with your proposal.

Comment: I totally agree that types are the most important thing and highly matter. That's why I'm so confused that there is no type analysis to catch errors.

Comment: Stupid question: @OP are you using the https://www.julia-vscode.org/ extension? Further analysis could be done with https://github.com/aviatesk/JET.jl (maybe still a bit experimental).

Answer (score 1):

The [Julia VSCode extension](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode) highlights at least some of your issues.

[image: VSCode Julia Linting]

Note that linting is only active when the Julia file is inside a workspace (see https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/1105).

With [JET.jl](https://github.com/aviatesk/JET.jl) more issues can be identified:

```
julia> @report_call fun(5)
═════ 2 possible errors found ═════
┌ @ c:\Users\d90394\Downloads\Untitled-1.jl:2 NonExistingStruct
│ `Main.NonExistingStruct` is not defined
└─────────────────────────────────────────────
┌ @ c:\Users\d90394\Downloads\Untitled-1.jl:2 n |> 2
│┌ @ operators.jl:911 f(x)
││ no matching method found `(::Int64)(::Int64)`: f::Int64(x::Int64)
│└────────────────────
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear: this is the best julia linting can do in a code editor right now? People really work on big projects with that lack of type checking? If so I'm pretty sad about it, coming from languages with strong type checking.

Comment: As a dynamically typed language, type checking in compile-time is not really feasible in Julia (analogue to other dynamical languages like Python, JavaScript). Usually this topic is covered by unit tests. In addition, Jet looks promising for type checking (and other aspects) before runtime (analogue to mypy for Python).